# akkaでwithRouterするとcontext.parentがとれなくなる

Tags: scala, akka

親-子のアクターで、withRouter()を使いルーターを設定すると子がcontext.parentを参照できなくなります。解決方法と理由が知りたくて質問しました。

まずcontext.parentが参照できる例

```
case object Ping
case object Pong

object Sample1 {

  def run() = {
    val system = ActorSystem()
    val parent = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[Parent]), "parent")
    parent ! Ping
  }

  class Parent extends Actor {

    val worker = context.actorOf(Props(classOf[Child]), "child")

    def receive = {
      case Ping =>
        worker ! Ping
      case Pong =>
        println("PONG!")
    }
  }

  class Child extends Actor {

    def receive = {
      case Ping =>
        println(context.parent)
        context.parent ! Pong
    }
  }

}
```

printで

> Actor[akka://default/user/parent#-1479915643]
>   PONG!

このように出力がされ、期待通りに動いてます。

workerを作るところで、withRouterを設定すると

```
val worker = context.actorOf(Props(classOf[Child]).withRouter(RoundRobinPool(3)), "child")
```

結果が

> Actor[akka://default/user/parent/child#-761629135]

このようにPONG!が出なくなり、context.parentが自身のchildになってます。

もちろんsenderでやれば送り元の親に返せるんですが、postRestart等でフックしたときにsenderだと親に返せなくて、context.parentにしたらこの現象に遭遇したという感じです。

詳しい方ご教授ください。

よろしくおねがいします m(_ _ )m

Answer (score 1):

自分もあまり詳しくないですが、公式ドキュメントに以下のような例や記述があるので

```
val escalator = OneForOneStrategy() {
  case e ⇒ testActor ! e; SupervisorStrategy.Escalate
}
val router = system.actorOf(RoundRobinPool(1, supervisorStrategy = escalator).props(
  routeeProps = Props[TestActor]))
```

- http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.10/scala/routing.html#supervision
- https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.3.10/akka-actor-tests/src/test/scala/akka/routing/RoutingSpec.scala#L143-L149

router作成時の`RoundRobinPool`のコンストラクタなどを経由して、自分で設定するとかでしょうか？

Comment: context.parentでrouterを参照するのは変わりないですが、たしかに

`val worker = context.actorOf(RoundRobinPool(3).props(routeeProps = Props[Child]), "router")`

こっちのほうが直感的で分かりやすいですね...。ありがとうございます!

Answer (score 1):

- 親 / 子

という階層が、routerを生成した場合には

- 親 / router / 子

となるので、この場合には子からparentを見たらrouterになります。context.parentの動作としては、おかしくなってはいません。(子という名前のまま統一しましたが、routerを使った方では階層上は、親から見たら孫になりました)
公式の説明で該当するのは、 http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.10/scala/routing.html#supervision の以下の部分です。

> Routees that are created by a pool router will be created as the router's children.

質問主さんのコードでは、routerにchildと名前を付けているので、context.parentとして表示されているのはChildクラスのActorではなくて、childという名前のrouterです。

```
val worker = context.actorOf(Props(classOf[Child]).withRouter(RoundRobinPool(3)), "router")
```

これで生成したとして、parentとselfをprintlnするようにしてPingを3連射してみると、router/$aとかrouter/$bとかに配置されているのがわかります。

```
self: Actor[akka://default/user/parent/router/$a#-1029801143]
parent: Actor[akka://default/user/parent/router#-1266735066]
self: Actor[akka://default/user/parent/router/$b#1593806271]
parent: Actor[akka://default/user/parent/router#-1266735066]
self: Actor[akka://default/user/parent/router/$c#1456555264]
parent: Actor[akka://default/user/parent/router#-1266735066]
```

senderでダメなケースの詳細がわかりませんが、そちらを突き詰めた方がよいのかもしれません。

Comment: なるほどよく分かりました!
ありがとうございました。